# Car acting up during ignition

Tags: engine, battery, polo

I have a Volkswagen Polo. The problem is that it is not getting started sometimes. But sometimes it's get ignited without any problem. I took it to the service centre of Volkswagen. They just tried to start it and without any inspection told me that my car battery is nearly dead. But here is something contradictory which I noted.  After remaining parked for even days my cars starts without any problem. But when I drive it and then stop anywhere and switch off the engine then it won't start. So if battery is nearly dead how is it possible that it is getting started without a problem after long standing but not after driving. Moreover when it doesnt start the brakes are heavily jammed. And are not pressable.

Comment: Well the brakes would be expected as you use up the “saved” vacuum from last engine start, is your engine smoking or anything like that? Fuel filter and pump alright? And also very important if you can remove the spark plugs and check for any abnormalities

Comment: Yup fuel pump and filter are alright. But I think I should check the spark plugs. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Maybe the starter is going or something related to that, but this is just a guess on my part